# Is there a defined meaning to the getcontentlength property on a collection?

Tags: webdav

The response fragment below is part of a PROPFIND reply:

```
<D:response>
<D:href>https://dav.mystery-meat.com/top</D:href>
<D:propstat>
<D:prop>
<D:creationdate ns0:dt="dateTime.tz">1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</D:creationdate>
<D:getcontentlanguage>en</D:getcontentlanguage>
<D:getcontentlength>16384</D:getcontentlength>
<D:getcontenttype>httpd/unix-directory</D:getcontenttype>
<D:getlastmodified ns0:dt="dateTime.rfc1123">Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT</D:getlastmodified>
<D:resourcetype><D:collection/></D:resourcetype>
</D:prop>
<D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
</D:propstat>
</D:response>
```

The `getcontentlength` value isn't the total bytes of items within this directory.  Is there any predefined meaning for this value in WebDAV or is it simply implementor-defined by each server that happens to report a value?

I.e. is it of any real use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-15.3), as usual it has a perfect definition:

> Purpose: Contains the Content-Length header returned by a GET without accept headers.

If that isn't clear, it basically says, if you perform a `GET` request on the same resource with no `Accept-*` headers, the response will report a `Content-Length` that is this value.

So if you have a WebDAV implementation that conforms to the standard, you should be able to easily test this by just executing a `GET` request on the collection. Chances are you'll get some automatically generated HTML response.

If the response to this `GET` request is a different size (in bytes) as it reported via `{DAV:}getcontentlength`, it should be considered a bug.

I think in your particular case it might be a bug. The fact that the reported size for the collection is exactly a power of two, leads me to believe that this particular server returns the result of `stat()` for that directory, which is simply how much space the directory listing takes up on the filesystem (the same number as when you use `ls`).

If my hunch is true, the server basically has broken behavior.

Comment: Yes, I read the RFC of course.  I suppose a server implementation *must* return `getcontentlength` based on that, but "correct" behavior or not the value looks basically useless aside from some contrived case of preallocating buffer space for a subsequent GET.  I suspect what we really have is a silly flaw in the design of WebDAV and collections pointlessly return a value.

Comment: It's not at all a flaw in the WebDAV spec. There's perfectly legitimate use-cases when resources exhibit both collection and file-like behavior. In addition, returning `{DAV:}getcontentlength` is not a _must_. What you're looking at is a bug in your server. Your implementation should simply not have returned anything for collections.

Comment: Well as the RFC says the server *must* return it for collections as long as it returns results for vanilla GETs on them.  So I don't see a server bug and I'm puzzled why you want to declare this particular server to be buggy.  What it does return on a simple GET is indeed an HTML page directory list, though I haven't verified that the length value matches exactly.

Comment: Compare it. I could be wrong, but I have a strong suspicion that it's different.